# Как лучше всего передать огромное количество id'шников?

Tags: c#, ajax, asp

Сайт построен на ASP и C# (это уже печалит).
Есть большая таблица. У каждой строки свой id. Нужно при нажатии на кнопку отправить список/массив этих id на сервер с помощью AJAX (метод GET). 
Внимание, вопрос! 
Каким образом лучше всего формировать строку данных в ajax'e для передачи на сервер? Можно ли там передавать/принимать массивы? Что делать, если количество id под сотню?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Составляйте json-ответ и принимайте его.
У меня по схеме - sql -> сервер -> mobile. Передается через json по 500кб быстро.